# setting different spacing between bars in dodge graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, spacing

I want to plot a bar chart using ggplot geom_col. I have x variable, y variable and a fill variable. My fill variable has four groups. When I used geom_col position_dodge, it gives me the four bars per each x variable dodged together. I want no space between bar 1 and bar2 and bar3 and bar 4, but I need a little space between bar 2 and bar 3. Is there any way to set different spacing between the bars in geom col in ggplot2. Below is my code and data. I also pasted the design of the graph I want to produce from this data.

```
# packages 

library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


##########
#  sample data 
Food = c("meat", "meat", "meat", "meat", "wheat","wheat","wheat", "wheat", "maize","maize","maize","maize")

Subgroup = c("Male", "Female", "Urban", "Rural", "Male",  "Female", "Urban", "Rural",  "Male",  "Female","Urban", "Rural")

mean = c(8.66, 10.45,  9.88,  7.32, 21.04, 19.65, 20.26, 20.87, 51.06 , 44.51,  47.60, 48.40)

df <- data.frame(Food, Subgroup,  mean)




#Color code


colorPanel = c('#083c5d','#2d004b','#106d8e','#7d103d')

# bar chart


Plot_FBGDS <-  ggplot(df, aes(x = Food, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(-0.84), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(mean,"%"), y = mean + 2, color = Subgroup), stat = "identity", 
            size = 3, vjust = 0.5, face = "bold", family = "sans",   position = position_dodge(-0.88)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorPanel) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("meat",
                              "wheat",
                              "maize"))  + 
  
  coord_flip() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", family = "sans"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "sans", color = "black", size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x =  element_blank(), #(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", color = "black"),
        axis.line.y =  element_line(),
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(colour = "green"),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0, "cm"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "black", family = "sans"),
        # axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(8, 8, 8, 8), "mm")),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10, color = "black",family = "sans"),
        #panel.aborder = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
        # legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", linetype="solid", 
        #colour ="black", size = 0.2),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size= 7),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, family = "sans"),
        
        legend.margin=margin(t= -1, r= 2, b= 2, l= 2),
        legend.title =  element_blank(), 
        legend.key.height = unit(0.03, "npc"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.03, "npc"),
        #legend.key.size = unit(5, 'lines'),
        # legend.position = "bottom",
        # legend.direction="horizonatl",
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.70),  # right corner
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.y =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x =  element_blank())
```

Plot_FBGDS

## here is the design of the graph I want to produce

[image: example.png]

I don't know how to create the space between the 2nd and the 3rd bars of each variable plot.

Comment: Use food as a facet variable, fill as subgroup like you have, and some additional variable to split subgroup into the categories you want, which will be the x-axis variable. As far as keeping the question minimal (see [mcve]), which helps both your debugging and our helping you: you've included 30 lines of theme settings, none of which are crucial for this problem (a few could be relevant once you're at the point of cleaning up facets)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One option is to specify the amount of dodge 'manually' for each of the 4 groups, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#  sample data 
Food = c("meat", "meat", "meat", "meat", "wheat","wheat","wheat", "wheat", "maize","maize","maize","maize")
Subgroup = c("Male", "Female", "Urban", "Rural", "Male",  "Female", "Urban", "Rural",  "Male",  "Female","Urban", "Rural")
mean = c(8.66, 10.45,  9.88,  7.32, 21.04, 19.65, 20.26, 20.87, 51.06 , 44.51,  47.60, 48.40)
df <- data.frame(Food, Subgroup,  mean)

#Color code
colorPanel = c('#083c5d','#2d004b','#106d8e','#7d103d')

# Plot
Plot_FBGDS <-  ggplot(df, aes(x = Food, y = mean,  fill = Subgroup)) + 
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(c(-0.9, -1.1, -1.1, -0.9)), width = 0.82) + 
  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0,20, 40, 60,80), expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,100), 
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(mean,"%"), y = mean + 2, color = Subgroup), stat = "identity", 
            size = 3, vjust = 0.5, face = "bold", family = "sans",   position = position_dodge(-0.88)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorPanel) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("meat",
                              "wheat",
                              "maize"))  + 
  
  coord_flip() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values =  colorPanel) + 
  labs( x= " ", 
        y = " ") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", family = "sans"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "sans", color = "black", size = 14),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x =  element_blank(), #(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", color = "black"),
        axis.line.y =  element_line(),
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(colour = "green"),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0, "cm"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "black", family = "sans"),
        # axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(8, 8, 8, 8), "mm")),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 10, color = "black",family = "sans"),
        #panel.aborder = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size = 0.5),
        # legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", linetype="solid", 
        #colour ="black", size = 0.2),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size= 7),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, family = "sans"),
        
        legend.margin=margin(t= -1, r= 2, b= 2, l= 2),
        legend.title =  element_blank(), 
        legend.key.height = unit(0.03, "npc"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.03, "npc"),
        #legend.key.size = unit(5, 'lines'),
        # legend.position = "bottom",
        # legend.direction="horizonatl",
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.70),  # right corner
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.y =  element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x =  element_blank())
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: stat
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: face

Plot_FBGDS
#> Warning: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You will need to tweak the actual dodge values to suit (i.e. it might be `position = position_dodge(c(-0.8, -1, -1, -0.8))`, but I think this is a pretty straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!!